# Group actions: orbits equivalent to divisors?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does there exist a group with a group action, that acts on the set of natural numbers where the orbit of any natural number is the set of its divisors?

Comment: So $3$ is in the orbit of $6$ but $6$ is not in the orbit of $3$???

Comment: @Derek Good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orbits under group action partition the set, thus if the orbit of $8$ was the sets of its divisors, namely $\{1,2,4,8\}$, this also is the orbit of $2$, but it is certainly not the set of divisors of $2$. Thus, the answer is no.